# Is it possible for Angular.JS to save someone's previous activity?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app I've been building that displays products from an array. Using Angular.JS, I can pull this array to generate on my `view`. In my `view`, a client can sort and filter the list to find exactly what they want. Is there a way to save those filters, so if they were to click an item, go to that corresponding page, then come back?

As of right now, it will always load all results without filters, even if a client has clicked a filter or two before hand.

Is there anyway to save their selections or previous activity?

Comment: I've never actually heard of [localStorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)? How does it work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's more than one way to do what you want:

- Using $cookies(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies);
- Using localstorage( I use this module, it's very good - https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage);
- using $cacheFactory(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory), but with this option you will lose the data if user leaves the session;

In all cases, the idea is to save the filters and selection on the desired location and retrieve i when necessary.

hope it helps

Comment: Ah, I see, I am actually watching a tutorial video on `ngStorage` so far, I believe that is what I'm going to need.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same demand as you in the past and I used ngSotage. Very easy to implement and works like a charm

Comment: Yeah, the video I watched was doing it with a "Hello World" message. Now I guess I have to figure out a way to write out to remember any check boxes that were clicked. Thanks for the help, bummer both you and me are getting thumbed down, but oh well.

Comment: I didn't get why. Anyway, we save a json in the localstorage with all the options and retrieve it when the controller, using it as a model for the view. In my case the userID and searchId are the keys to find the right registry.

Comment: My assumption is due to no code, and it's more of a 'white-board' style discussion question.